# Is there a positive integer $n$ such that every $n$-Mersenne prime generates a prime?

Tags: number-theory, mersenne-numbers

First, some definitions. A $1$-Mersenne prime is just a Mersenne prime. Now, let $n$ be a positive integer. If $p$ is an $n$-Mersenne prime, and $2^p - 1$ is itself a prime, then $2^p - 1$ is said to be an $n+1$-Mersenne prime. A consequence of this definition is that, given positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m \leq n$, if $p$ is an $n$-Mersenne prime, then $p$ is also an $m$-Mersenne prime. My question is, does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that whenever $p$ is an $n$-Mersenne prime, then $2^p - 1$ is also a prime? Now, I know that it has not yet been proven that there are infinitely many Mersenne prime numbers, but perhaps my statement can be refuted.

Comment: It has been proven that there are infinitely many primes. What hasn't been proven is that there are infinitely many **Mersenne** primes.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Sorry about that! I edited the question to fix it.

Comment: 1. It is conjectured that there are infinite many Mersenne primes because of heuristic arguments , but as mentioned not proven 2. What you mean is probably a double Mersenne prime , called $M(M(p))$. Since the sequence of those numbers grows very quickly , it is highly likely that there are only very few of those primes.

Comment: 3. I do not know the complete current status , for some small prime , there are double Mersenne primes and for some other small primes , factors are known (showing that they are not prime). We can safely assume that the known list is already the complete list.

Comment: 4. If we iterate a third time , the numbers are then already so big (unless we start with a very small prime) that there is almost no chance left that we get a prime. In particular , it is almost impossible that this chain will continue forever.